# Targeting the correct element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

A tooltip library is copying the dom node to insert the html inside a tooltip.

**I need to target the element inside the tooltip, but the javascript is always applied to the original element.**

```
 <a class="tooltip">Open</a>

<div class="tooltip-html" style="display:none;">
<div id="main-content" class="scroll">
    <div class="Content">
        <div class="blue">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using the enter callback of the tooltip, this was not working. And applying things before the html is copied by the tooltip only cosmetically works, the javascript is still looking at the original. I even tried changing the class before I apply anymore javascript. Figuring if I changed the class the original element would no longer be accessible. The class changed, but the javascript was not applied to what was inside the tooltip.

Is there a good way remove a div once it has been copied, or a better method of finding/targeting the correct element.

```
$(this).find("div.scroll").test();
```

EDIT:

```
...Before...
    <div id="main-content" class="scroll">
    <div class="Content"> 

...After...

<div id="tiptip_holder" style="max-width: 230px; margin: 23px 0pt 0pt 999px; display: none;" class="tip_left_bottom">
<div id="tiptip_arrow" style="margin-left: 220px; margin-top: -12px;">
<div id="tiptip_content">
    <div id="main-content" class="scroll">
    <div class="Content"> 
    ....
```

The **this** was a part of the enter callback for the tooltip library:

```
 var tip_html = $('.tooltip-html').html();
    $('.tooltip').tipTip({ content: tip_html, enter: function(){
        $(this).find("div.scroll").test();

    }
```

Also tried using,

```
$("#main-content.scroll", "#tiptip_content").test();
```

**UPDATE:**

As people mentioned naming the parent div like I was should of worked, here's an example of how i'm not able to target inside the tooltip.

[jsfiddle.net/mstefanko/pUm5V/24](http://jsfiddle.net/mstefanko/pUm5V/24)

```
//$("#main-content", "#tooltip-content").css("background", "red");
$("#main-content", "#tiptip_content").css("background", "blue");
```

Blue doesn't work, red does. I feel like both lines should work.

Comment: What is `this` in your example code?  Also, have you looked at the DOM to see what it looks like after the copy, with firebug or something similar to ensure the html wasn't modified?

Comment: Edited the question with answers to these, there is additional divs wrapping the html, but the html is not modified in any way.

Comment: When you use `$(this)` you are referring to the encasing function's selected element. In the case above `$(this)` would refer to `$('.tooltip')`. Not sure why `$("#main-content.scroll", "#tiptip_content").test();` isn't working for you though. I made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUm5V/7/) to just test the selection and it seems to be working with the HTML you posted.

Comment: Yeah that's weid, `$("#main-content.scroll", "#tiptip_content").test()` should be working. You can try `$("#tiptip_content .scroll").test();`, but I don't see why it would work if the first one failed.

And btw, did you define this test() function? Because I don't see it in jQuery.

Comment: I defined test, and was just an example. But you can see in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mstefanko/pUm5V/24/

//$("#main-content", "#tooltip-content").css("background", "red");
$("#main-content", "#tiptip_content").css("background", "blue");

The red works, the blue doesn't. Even without worrying about applying things to the right element, I can't target inside the tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the main cause of my issue. The following lines in the plugin:

```
function active_tiptip(){
    opts.enter.call(this);        
    tiptip_content.html(org_title);
```

the enter call was being called before any of the tooltip content was in the DOM, as much as the wrappers for the tooltip existed, calling main-content when it wasn't in the tooltip yet will obviously fail to work. Not sure i've completely solved my issue, but reversing these lines fixes the question at hand.